# What to do when we have a fractional part of $x$?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How to find

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\{x\}}{\tan\{x\}}$$

Where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: Recall that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Comment: It won't help here

Comment: @ajotatxe so the LHL is tan 1 and RHL is 1?

Answer (score 5):

The limit from the right side is easy.  Notice that for $x\in(0,1)$, $\{x\}=x$, thus

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\{x\}}{\tan\{x\}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac x{\tan(x)}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\cos(x)\frac x{\sin(x)}=\cos(0)\times1=1$$

Which follows nicely from the famous $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$ limit.

Now notice that for $x\in(-1,0)$, $\{x\}=x+1$, thus

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\{x\}}{\tan\{x\}}=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{x+1}{\tan(x+1)}=\frac1{\tan(1)}$$

Since the left and right limits don't agree... the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\{x\}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\{x\}=1$$
since $-1<x<0$ implies $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor=x-(-1)=x+1$.
Then
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\{x\}}{\tan\{x\}}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac t{\tan t}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\{x\}}{\tan\{x\}}=\lim_{t\to 1}\frac t{\tan t}$$

Comment: Sorry I don't follow u

Comment: Oh, seems like joeb deleted his comment.

Comment: As I did mine?  :D